# Execute curl command from Cypress

Tags: curl, cypress

Is there any way to execute curl command from Cypress and read the response from the command?

I can execute the curl command from command line and could see the response on the command line.

However, I want to execute the curl command from Cypress and also want to read the output of the curl command.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cy.exec` method for that:

```js
cy.exec('curl https://example.com').then(result => {
  // yields the 'result' object
})
```

Read more about the [method](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/exec#Syntax).